# JavaScript Student Number Validation question

Tags: javascript

new to this so hopefully my question is specific enough for it to make sense.

I am trying to create a webpage that validates a "Student Number" ---

- must start with an "A"
- following the A there must be exactly 8 numerical digits,
- but they cannot be all 0's

For example A89071231 would be a valid student number, but A00000000 would not be, nor would just "A" or "A123".

The user's input must be A + exactly 8 digits that are not all zeros.

What I have so far is this below. Where "StudentNo" = an HTML id tag and the "calculate" function is to total the students grade average.

I just need help figuring out how to write the code so that each digit following the first character A can be anything between 0-9 and still give a valid input, besides a situation where the user inputs all 0's after the "A".

I figured regex would be the easiest way to do it, or by using substr() or substring() but I am not very familiar with JavaScript and can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong with it.

Thanks for any help you can give!!!

```
function calculate();
var sno = $("StudentNo").value.trim();
if(sno === "" || !sno.startsWith("A") {
  alert("Student Number is missing, please enter your Student A Number.");
  $("StudentNo").focus();
  return;
}
```

Comment: Try using regex: [`/^A(?!0+$)\d{8}$/.test(sno)`](https://regex101.com/r/4FkXp3/1/)

Comment: Wow perfect that worked! Thanks so much. Can you point me to some useful videos/articles on regex? The regex101 website seems very useful. Thanks again

Comment: If you're beginner, my suggestion is, try to [learn the basics and common syntax](https://github.com/ziishaned/learn-regex) first, then take some [iteractive quiz](https://regexone.com/). Using a [regex debugger](https://regex101.com/) always helps, after that you may go through some [advanced challenges](https://regex101.com/quiz).

Comment: Yes I am a beginner, thank you for these links I will definitely check them out as I struggle understanding regex. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I like using [https://regexr.com/](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to handle 3 conditioin as

**1)** `!sno.startsWith("A")`

**2)** `sno.length !== 9`

**3)** `sno.slice(1).match(/0{8}/)`

```js
function validateSNo(sno) {
  if (!sno.startsWith("A") || sno.length !== 9 || sno.slice(1).match(/0{8}/)) {
    // alert("Student Number is missing, please enter your Student A Number.");
    // $("StudentNo").focus();
    console.log(
      "Student Number is missing, please enter your Student A Number."
    );
  } else {
    console.log("Perfect student number")
  }
}

validateSNo("S");
validateSNo("A00000000");
validateSNo("A123");
validateSNo("A12345678");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following answers will help you

**I have checked following thinks**

- First character A or not
- Rest of the first character has only number or not (A12345678 is valid, A1234567B invalid)
- Rest of the first character has 8 digits or not (A + 8 digits or not)
- Rest of the first character has only 0 value or not (A00000000 or not)

**Code Snippet**

```js
function checkStudentNumber(studentNumber){
  var sno = studentNumber; // get student number
  
  var checkInitialCharacter = sno.charAt(0) === "A" ? true : false; // check studentno first character A or not, if A output will be true
  
  var exeptFirstLetter = sno.slice(1); // Separate execpt first character from string
  
  var checkexeptFirstLetterCharactersLength  = exeptFirstLetter.length == 8 ? true : false; // character separated charactee count qual to 8 or not, if YES output will be true.
  
  var checkExceptFirstCharacters = /^\d+$/.test(exeptFirstLetter) ? true : false; // confirm rest of the first character has only numbers.
  
  var convertExecptFirstlettersintoNumber = checkExceptFirstCharacters ? parseFloat(exeptFirstLetter) : null; // convert rest of the first character into number
  
  var checkZeroValues =  convertExecptFirstlettersintoNumber === 0 ? true : false; // check  rest of the first character has only zero digits or not, 
  
  
  if(!checkInitialCharacter || checkZeroValues || !checkexeptFirstLetterCharactersLength || !checkExceptFirstCharacters ){
    alert(studentNumber + " : Student Number is missing, please enter your Student A Number.");
  } else {
    alert(studentNumber + " : Perfect student number");
  }
}


checkStudentNumber("A00000000"); // Output: Student Number is missing, please enter your Student A Number.
checkStudentNumber("B00000000"); // Output: Student Number is missing, please enter your Student A Number.
checkStudentNumber("A12345"); // Output: Student Number is missing, please enter your Student A Number.
checkStudentNumber("A12345678"); // Output: Perfect student number.
checkStudentNumber("ABCD78"); // Output: Student Number is missing, please enter your Student A Number.
checkStudentNumber("A0000000B"); // Output: Student Number is missing, please enter your Student A Number.
checkStudentNumber("A12345B78"); // Output: Student Number is missing, please enter your Student A Number.
checkStudentNumber("A45645678"); // Output: Perfect student number.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with [Negative lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet#other_assertions),
using the group: `(?!0{8})`. We'd follow this with the required 8 digits `(\d{8})`.

We'd wrap this up in a function `checkStudentNumber()`, which takes the student number as the only parameter and returns a boolean true/false value indicating if the number is valid.

```js
function checkStudentNumber(number) { 
    return /^A(?!0{8})(\d{8})$/.test(number)
}

const numbers = ['A12345670', 'A00000001', 'A00010000', 'A12345678','A00000000', 'A1234567', 'A123456789', 'GARBAGE'];
console.log('Tests:');
console.log('\nNumber  \tValid');
numbers.forEach(number => console.log(number.padEnd(8, ' '), '\t', checkStudentNumber(number) ? 'Yes': 'No'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```